# Does anyone knows when will image from text will be available on Azure OpenAI Services?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-openai

That's pretty much it, I'm wondering if Azure OpenAI Services will integrate a DALL-E2 like service where I provide a description and it would generate an image.

Also, is there a roadmap somewhere, I wasn't able to find it myself...

I built a solution on Power Automate using the new OpenAI connector, it uses a credit system however so billing for the company would be easier if it was an Azure service.

Answer (score 1):

Please submit this [form](https://customervoice.microsoft.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR7en2Ais5pxKtso_Pz4b1_xUOFA5Qk1UWDRBMjg0WFhPMkIzTzhKQ1dWNyQlQCN0PWcu) to access the DALLE 2.

[image]

The #Bing Image Creator preview.  it just uses #DALLE2 in the background but it's a nice UX and has some good prompt guidance.